# Is it possible to install Xcode 7 in 10.9 OS X?

Tags: macos, xcode

I have very slow Mac with an HDD (MacBook C2D 2.24Ghz/2.40Ghz) and there is no possibility to install El Capitan or Yosemite (very,very slow).

I want to use a newer Xcode to learn programming though.

Is there a way to install a newer Xcode with OS X (10.9) – maybe there is patch for Xcode or some hack for exec?

Comment: You'll need El Capitan for the latest version of XCode. El Capitan is very fast, and you might find it faster than Mavericks even on your slow machine.

Comment: @JohnRamos Yeah, I have a Core 2 Duo Mac and El Cap runs well on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wish to remain on Mavericks and not upgrade to El Capitan I would suggest installing it on an external drive or partitioning your main drive just for a test. Make a new 60 gb partition(just in case you actually like El Capitan) and if you are not satisfied with its productivity, trash it. I guess you could use it just as a "developer" OS and switch to it only when you'll be using it but that in my opinion would be inconvenient. I am using El Capitan on 2008 MacBook Pro the OS itself runs perfectly. The startup is a bit slow compared to most newer computers and the CPU isn't the best(2x2.4Ghz) but it works fine for such an old machine.

Comment: yeah, i agree (i have 2 macbooks 2.2Ghz -2009 2.4Ghz macbook 2010 - 5 gb-all), if  use as usual it's normal, if i want use for programming it's like a lazy cat slow start, slow think . playground is one big bug on my mac. i Use IBM Sandbox for it

Comment: @jcmaxuser Well, you'll just have to use El Capitan anyway or lose the latest XCode.

Answer (score 0):

You should download El Capitan anyway; if Apple lets you download it onto your machine, it'll work well enough (they have a firm grasp on how well their each of their hardware run each software). Also, Red Eagle 2000 just said, "I have a Core 2 Duo Mac and El Cap runs well on it."

So go ahead and download El Capitan and the latest version of Xcode; I really doubt you'll regret it.

Comment: yeah i can download and install 10.11, but it's not useable as i want.  i have installed OS X 10.11   with 5gb DDR3 && SSD but it's still working slow when i open more then 5 apps including xcode its working slow. Here you can watch benchmarks of my old macbook 2009/2010. when i disables SIP it's more speedy